# Wrapper / decorator - Get the value of a variable of the method it executes

Tags: python-3.x, variables, wrapper

Is it possible, in a wrapper / decorator, to get the value of a variable inside the method it executes?

In this example, I would like to print the content of the variable **helloThere** directly in the wrapper.

Actually, I need to execute some other commands (in another class) depending on this variable directly from the wrapper.

```
from functools import wraps

class myclass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def _wrapped(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print(helloThere)
        return wrapper

    @_wrapped
    def doA(self):
        helloThere = "Obi-Wan Kenobi"

    @_wrapped
    def doB(self):
        helloThere = "General Grievous"
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Holy Hack, This is not optimized, and probably a billion ways it can go wrong, but it goes to show how freakin' amazing Python is.

I'll be interested if there is something more elegant out there.

(Should you choose to use it, you are tasked with the effort of fitting into a decorator.)

```
from dill.source import getsourcelines

# Some arbitrary method, that the decorator would wrap.
def print_hi():
    var = 1
    var2 = 2
    return var2

# converts the print_hi method into lines of code
lines = getsourcelines(print_hi)[0]

# rebuild, yielding the variable you want after it is defines. 
# you would need to add some complexity to search for the variable
# definition
new_lines = [lines[0], lines[1], "    yield var\n", lines[2], lines[3]]

# Re - hydrate into code
f = ''.join(new_lines)

# Make the function return statement a yield statement, so you 
# can get at it. 
f = f.replace("return", "yield")

# re-define the method. Note, you would probably want to replace 
# the method name as well so you don't monkey patch it everywhere
# it is used. 
exec(f)

# In your decorator, you can now for-loop on the function, since you
# converted it to yield instead of return.
for i in print_hi():
    print(i)
```

Again, this is just a proof of concept. It would take a lot of work to make it robust -- but it can be done.